# Initialise a list to a specific length in Python

Tags: python, list

How do I initialise a list with 10 times a default value in Python?

I'm searching for a good-looking way to initialize a empty list with a specific range. 
So make a list that contains 10 zeros or something to be sure that my list has a specific length.

Answer (score 378, accepted):

If the "default value" you want is immutable, @eduffy's suggestion, e.g. `[0]*10`, is good enough.

But if you want, say, a list of ten `dict`s, do *not* use `[{}]*10` -- that would give you a list with the **same** initially-empty `dict` ten times, **not** ten distinct ones. Rather, use `[{} for i in range(10)]` or similar constructs, to construct ten separate `dict`s to make up your list.

Comment: or [{} for _ in range(10)] to avoid lint warnings

Comment: something like [0] * 10 is not the way to create 2d list. If you create a list `l = [[0]*10]*10]`, try change `l[0][0] = 100`, you will find that l[1][0], l[2][0] ... l[9][0] are all set to 100. It is because `*` replicates reference for object.

Comment: Just hit that one.  Wound up with [['' for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)] instead of >>> card_strings = [['']*5]*5
>>> card_strings[0][0] = "Well that was unexpected..."

Answer (score 192):

list multiplication works.

```
>>> [0] * 10
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 56):

In a talk about core containers internals in Python at PyCon 2012, Raymond Hettinger is suggesting to use `[None] * n` to pre-allocate the length you want.

[Slides available as PPT](https://web.archive.org/web/20130615024815/http://www.pycon.it/media/stuff/slides/core-python-containers-under-hood.ppt) or [via Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=hettinger%20python%20core%20containers%20pycon%20slide%201)

The whole slide deck is quite interesting.
The [presentation is available on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYUsssClE94), but it doesn't add much to the slides.