# Initialise array of empty arrays

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
a = [[]] * 10
a[0].append(1)
print a # Outputs [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

How can I get `a` to output

```
[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list

Comment: [Initialise a list to a specific length in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983699/initialise-a-list-to-a-specific-length-in-python)

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: That's not the same question, although there are countless duplicates on SO.

Comment: @Wooble No, it's not, but the answer from Alex Martelli also answers this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
a=[[] for i in xrange(10)]
```

In your code you're adding the same list 10 times. The following output should clarify this:

```
>>> a=[[]] * 5
>>> for i in a: print id(i)
... 
155302636
155302636
155302636
155302636
155302636
>>> a=[[] for i in xrange(5)]
>>> for i in a: print id(i)
... 
155302668
155302732
155302924
155303020
155303052
```

As you can see, in the first example `a` contains 5 times a reference to the same array object, in the second example it contains references to 5 different array objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code creates an array containing the same array ten times.

Use `[[] for i in xrange(10)]` so you actually create separate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> a = [[] for i in range(10)]
>>> a[0].append(1)
>>> a
[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```