# What is the best practice way to create a list of 1 element type

Tags: python

For example, I want a list that looks like this: `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

I could either create it:

```
l = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Or I could multiple a single list containing solely the element 5 times:

```
l = [1] * 5
```

Or I could use a list comprehension:

```
l = [1 for i in range(5)]
```

Of these three ways, which is fastest and best practice?

I somehow remember the second approach being problematic because each position in the list will contain the same memory address, so updating one index will cause all elements in the list to be updated to the same value. However, after tinkering with it this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: The problem with the second only exists with *mutable* types. `int`s are immutable, so no problem with approach #2.

Comment: for fastest: run a benchmark. best practice: probably depends on who you are asking... not all your examples always work.

Comment: It depends... approach 2 and 3 have the advantage of having a size O(log n) in the number of elements, the first is O(n) which becomes cumbersome if you replace `5` with say, 20, 100, or 10000.

Comment: wrt/ the second approach, the problem is not with rebinding an index in the list (ie `lst[2] = None`), which will only make `lst[2]` point to something else and leave the rest alone, but if your list is built from a mutable object, if you mutate it, this will _of_ course_ affect the other indices since they are all pointing to the same object. Cf https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for more on the topic

Comment: From the comments so far, it seems like #3 is the winner, though #2 is fine when the list elements are immutable, and #1 is fine when the list is small. Maybe we should compile this into a community wiki answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialise a list to a specific length in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983699/initialise-a-list-to-a-specific-length-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

**Two better cases for mutable objects:**

```
import copy

class A:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value

_LEN_OF_LIST = 5

# object could be created quickly
l = [A(value=100500) for i in range(_LEN_OF_LIST)]

# creating of object is expensive operation
default_object = A(value=100500)    # mutable object which
l = [copy.deepcopy(default_object) for i in range(_LEN_OF_LIST)]

# addresses
print('\r\n'.join([str(obj) for obj in l]))
```

**Output:**

```
<__main__.A object at 0x0000028A9BD45B00>
<__main__.A object at 0x0000028A9BC17EB8>
<__main__.A object at 0x0000028A9BC17AC8>
<__main__.A object at 0x0000028A9BC17B38>
<__main__.A object at 0x0000028A9BC17DA0>
```

As you can see: each object has got own address in memory